# Is it possible to miss the ending scene?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I was wondering...

I played through AC4 when it came out on the PS3, and I watched every scene.

This year I decided to replay it and noticed a new scene which I apparently missed somehow.

It's the scene at the ending where:

> Kenway takes his kids to the theatre.

I had never seen it before and I didn't skip the credits so I was wondering where it came from.

Can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the scene played after the credits.  Its been there the entire time as far as I know (I remember seeing the scene when I first played the game when it came out).  Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjn5hfe5jAs).  Around the 3:08 mark the credits begins.  At around 7:36, the credits end, and the cut scene you are talking about begins.  This video was posted October 28th 2013.  The game was released October 29th 2013 (Not sure how the days are off by one).

Comment: I can confirm it's been there all along. Having myself been a part of the production team of AC4, I can assure this scene definitely was in the game since the first day it came out (and even before :)).